# How to upstart Debian Chroot on Synology to run Homebridge

Tags: linux, debian, nas, synology, chroot

I have a synology diskstation that I want to use to run homebridge. I have got homebridge working by installing the debian package for chroot and installing all the necessary things in chroot to get homebridge working; and it works great! I am not very well versed in CLI for linux. What I do to get homebridge running is open terminal from my mac, SSH into my synology and run chroot with the following command:

```
sudo /var/packages/debian-chroot/scripts/start-stop-status chroot
```

Once I type in my password for sudo, I am in a chroot instance and I then simply type:

```
homebridge
```

All is well and running so long as I do not close my terminal window or restart my synology. Now there lies the problem. I do not want to have my laptop terminal open to have this running since that defeats the purpose of having homebridge run on my synology, and, I do not want to have to log back in to the synology to start this process manually when the synology restarts.

Can anyone give advice on how to get this process automated on the synology? I have tried this upstart script within the synology environment, but have had no luck (I have also tried splitting the script up into synology linux instance and then doing another upstart script in debian chroot to do the homebridge start, that didn't work either):

```
description "start debian and homebridge"

console log

start on syno.share.ready and  syno.network.ready

stop on runlevel [06]

exec sudo /var/packages/debian-chroot/scripts/start-stop-status chroot
exec homebridge
```

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: This may be weird, but have you tried running `homebridge &` which should then run homebridge in the background?

Answer (score 1):

You start the services in the Debian-Chroot evironment from the DSM task scheduler. The GUI of the chroot app is broken in DSM6, so you have to work around it at the moment. Services information is stored in a SQLite database. Consult a SQL FAQ on how to query, insert, update and delete rows of data in a table of such a database. If your application has a start script and creates a PID file when running, the Synology chroot application takes care of starting and restarting daemons.

Ref: https://github.com/SynoCommunity/spksrc/wiki/Debian-Chroot